# Validate select option - Duplicate selection option must not be select twice

Tags: javascript

I have this select input. It will be put in the form multiple times since they also have quantity each.
So the select input will be shown again but i want it to restrict an option that is already selected. Not necessarily to hide the selected input but to prompt an alert whenever the user chooses an option which is already in the form.

```
<select class="form-control" name="supplier[]" id="supplier[]">
    <option value="0">Select Item</option>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
    <option value="{{{ $item->id }}}">{{{ $item->code}}} - {{{ $item->description}}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Can you add some of your javascript for select validation?

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary of values => counts and when adding to the dictionary check if the key already exists.

Something like this should work:

```
var counts = {};
$("select[name='supplier[]']").each(function(i, el) {
    var val = $(el).val();
    if (typeof counts[val] == 'undefined') {
        counts[val] = 1;   
    } else {
        alert('value ' + val + ' entered more than once');   
    }
});
```